# HTTP POST Request Problems

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-post

I have a simple form that send data to a server via POST message. However, i am getting the error of "Unable to execute query" whenever i click the submit button. Here is my implementation:

**sample.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
        function pullMore(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome,etc.
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{ // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    document.getElementById("news_mesgs").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");
            var comments = document.getElementById("comment");
            var parameters="name"+name.value+"&email="+email.value+"&comments="+comments.value;

            xmlhttp.open("POST", "reviews.php", true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xmlhttp.send(parameters);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color : #e9e9e9;">
<div> Hello there </div>
<form>
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    Comment: <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment">
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="pullMore()">
</form>


<div id="news_mesgs"> come here </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**reviews.php**

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


$query = 'INSERT INTO Reviews (Name, Email, Review) VALUES ('.$_POST['name'].','.$_POST['email'].','.$_POST['comments'].');';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( "Unable to execute query");
```

Update: For some reason `$_POST["name"]` is appearing empty. I tried to `print var_dump($_POST);` for some sample data and this is what i got:
array(2) { ["email"]=> string(11) "abc@abc.com" ["comments"]=> string(5) "hello" } Unable to execute query

Comment: Your query failed for some reason.  But why it failed depends on what was posted for the value of `name`.  Check your database logs.  After you figure this out, clean up that gaping security hole.  Someone could post a name of `Robert');drop table Reviews;--` and you would be sad.

Comment: i tried to echo $_POST['name'] but it returns empty and then the usual error message (Unable to execute query)

Comment: your codes is vulnerable, **SQL INJECTION**

Comment: You have an error in `var parameters`. You forgot to add `=` to `"name"+name.value`. It should be `"name="+name.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing assignment operator. You are not sending name properly and thats why query fails.

Try using

```
var parameters="name="+name.value+"&email="+email.value+"&comments="+comments.value;
```

You are also missing quotes. Use

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO Reviews (Name, Email, Review) VALUES ("'.$_POST['name'].'","'.$_POST['email'].'","'.$_POST['comments'].'");';
```

**Or a little bit better**

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO Reviews (Name, Email, Review) VALUES ("'.mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']).'","'.mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']).'","'.mysql_escape_string($_POST['comments']).'");';
```

And don't just insert post variables into query. It's straight way to SQL injection.

Check [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: even after i change the javascript i am still getting unable to execute query

Comment: Try to `die(mysql_error())` instead of `die( "Unable to execute query")` and post result

Comment: this is the response when i entered Samplename in name field: Unknown column 'Samplename' in 'field list'

Comment: My Table Structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Reviews` (
  `Name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `Review` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;